# How to inject the server port in Grails 4 integration tests?

Tags: grails-4

Since Grails 4 it is not possible anymore to get the server port in grails integration tests this way:

```
@Value('${local.server.port}')
Integer serverPort
```

What's the correct way to get the server port in tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serverPort is already injected in Grails 4 integration tests as `serverPort`. There is no need to create a variable for it.